# Modifiying parameters in postgresql.conf and SIGHUP

Tags: postgresql, configuration, signals

I modified the parameter **maintenance_work_mem** in postgresql.conf in my production environment. I'd like to know if I send a **SIGHUP** to the postgres process it will reload that variable, and if it's safe for such environment.

Answer (score 3):

From the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/postgres.1.html#contenttoc6):

> The  SIGHUP  signal  will  reload the server configuration files. It is also possible to send SIGHUP to an individual server process, but  that is usually not sensible.

So it should work. In general you can use the `reload` command of a service's initscript in order to trigger a reload (which may or may not use SIGHUP as the mechanism). If the service doesn't support this the initscript should report an error, so this is fairly safe to try.

Comment: I believe you can change `maintenace_work_mem` with a reload (`SIGHUP`) - After you reload the server connect to it and execute `SHOW maintenance_work_mem ;`-- If the value reflects your change you're good to go.  If not you will need to do a full restart.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a [SQL statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-admin.html) to reload the configuration:

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

You need superuser permissions.